# UIPopoverViewController-like element in Android

Tags: android, ipad, uipopovercontroller, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, uipopover

I am now porting a iPad application to Android tablets, and it uses a lot of UIPopoverViewController. I have tried creating a "layout" to show in fullscreen at front with a small content view, it works well, but I was wondering if there is a native element for this kind of functionality. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since not everybody helping Android developers has any clue what a "UIPopoverViewController" is, perhaps you might consider posting a screenshot somewhere of the effect you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking for QuickActionController in Android. And I don't think there is a native element available in Android. But still the examples below make use of a pop up dialog with some animations to make it look like popoverviewController, Here is a example to start with,

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/quick-action-demo/

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

[image]

Comment: Yeah thanks, I had found this component as well, I was just asking if there was a native way to do this :)

Comment: Oops.. Sorry I didn't know that. I don't think there is a native component available as of now.

Answer (score 5):

To help with this issue I have created a component that acts like a popover view. Be sure to check it out :)

https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView
[image: Screenshot]